# Error Message Variable does not exist

Tags: apex

Why does this code give me an error?

> Variable does not exist: incomingCase
>   global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){

```
 List<EmailMessage> lstEmailMessage = new List<EmailMessage>();
 Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
 List<String> toAddresses = email.toAddresses;

 try{
     System.debug('Not able to get Inside');

     if(toAddresses.size()>0){
         System.debug('Inside the to Addresses.size');
         Case incomingCase = new Case();
         incomingCase.Description = email.plainTextBody;
         incomingCase.Subject = email.subject;
         incomingCase.Status= 'New';    
         incomingCase.RecordTypeId = caseComplaintRecordType;
         incomingCase.Origin ='Support Email';       
         incomingCase.ContactId = email.fromName;  

         if(email.subject.contains('Nothing')){

         }


  }

  Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(incomingCase, True);
```

Comment: Removing all your code from every question is inappropriate behavior and will not be tolerated.

Comment: Please stop modifying your questions in a way that makes the posted answers nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you declare this inside if block. SO its scope is limited to if block and you are trying to access it outside if so declare it outside of if block

```
Case incomingCase = new Case();
  if(toAddresses.size()>0){
```

or you can move the insert inside if statement

```
if(toAddresses.size()>0){
         System.debug('Inside the to Addresses.size');
         Case incomingCase = new Case();
         incomingCase.Description = email.plainTextBody;
         incomingCase.Subject = email.subject;
         incomingCase.Status= 'New';    
         incomingCase.RecordTypeId = caseComplaintRecordType;
         incomingCase.Origin ='Support Email';       
         incomingCase.ContactId = email.fromName;  

         if(email.subject.contains('Nothing')){

         }
     Database.SaveResult srList = Database.insert(incomingCase, True);

  }
```

In first approach you need to make sure don't try to insert empty case record so it will be better if you move insert inside if block.